# How to use GetCurrentAuditScope metthod in an ActionFilterAttribute

Tags: audit.net

How to uses the GetCurrentAuditScope() (or another) method in an ActionFilterAtribbute on MVC and WebAPI to get the AuditScope.

I need recover that on OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext) event.

Or have another thing which i can uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `GetCurrentAuditScope()` Extension Method on `HttpContext`, for example:

```cs
using Audit.WebApi;
// ...

public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{
    var scope = context.HttpContext.GetCurrentAuditScope();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I a WebApi i got it, but in a MVC 5 i can't.

Comment: Oh you're right, there is no Extension Method for the MVC extension. You can create a new issue [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new) to ask for the extension method. In the meantime you can get the MVC action with `var action = (httpContext.Items["__private_AuditScope__"] as AuditScope)?.GetMvcAuditAction();` Don't forget the `using Audit.Mvc;`

Comment: I opened the issue [#492](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/492).

Thanks for instructions.

Comment: The extension method `GetCurrentAuditScope(this HttpContext)` was added on version 19.1.2

Comment: This answer is not clear.

Comment: @Subfuzion what do you think the answer needs to be more clear?